# Breaking a list in to parts by subject

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries. Each list can be assumed to have dictionaries of the same format. Let's call that format:

```
dict_sample={'a':0,'b':1}
```

Let's also say that `a` is a random integer, while b can be one of a few numbers (Or strings, for that matter). I'm wanting to sort all of the `a` values by `b`. For instance, if I had a list as follows:

```
a    b
54   1
25   0
53   1
532  2
132  0

list=[{'a':54,'b':1},{'a':25,'b':0},{'a':53,'b':1},{'a':532,'b':2},{'a':132,'b':0}]
```

I would like to break this down in to 3 lists. The lists would include (Order not important)

```
0 list-> [25,132]
1 list-> [54,53]
2 list-> [532]
```

I know I can break all `a`'s from the list as follows, but I can't quite figure out an elegant solution to sorting the `a`'s by `b`'s. Any suggestions? My code so far looks like:

```
[row['a'] for row in list]
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
index=0      #This could be looped through, or just chosen for one specific value
[row['a'] if row['b']==index for row in list]
```

Comment: Why don't you just have `(a, b)` tuples?

Comment: My real dictionaries are quite a bit longer, and I don't want to have to remember what the indexing scheme of them is. I'd just rather give each value a name.

Comment: `(a, b)` [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s may be useful, then.

Comment: Can't you just loop through each dictionary in the list and add to the proper sub-list based on the value of b? Or am I missing something here? ie. create a list for each value of b. Loop through all dictionaries. If(b == "type1"), add `a` to type1 list. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already knew all the `b` values, this would be trivial. You want a list for each `b` value, where each one has all of the `a` values in each dictionary with that `b` value. You can translate that almost directly from English to a comprehension:

```
[[d['a'] for d in lst if d['b']==b] for b in bs]
```

You don't have the `b` values, but you can get them just by doing another pass:

```
bs = (d['b'] for d in lst)
```

Except that you obviously only want unique values, and you want to iterate them in sorted order, so:

```
bs = sorted(set(d['b'] for d in lst))
```

And that's all there is to it. Putting it together:

```
>>> lst=[{'a':54,'b':1},{'a':25,'b':0},{'a':53,'b':1},{'a':532,'b':2},{'a':132,'b':0}]
>>> bs = sorted(set(d['b'] for d in lst))
>>> [[d['a'] for d in lst if d['b']==b] for b in bs]
[[25, 132], [54, 53], [532]]
```

Comment: All I had to do was to put the `if` after the `for` loop. Sigh. Thanks for pointing the error of my ways out!

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: Ah, I understand where you went wrong. When you first look at multi-clause comprehensions, many people expect it to go in inside-out order—the innermost expression is at the left, so it must nest right-to-left, right? But nope, the innermost expression is special and comes first, but the clauses nest left-to-right. (That's very hard to explain in a comment, but I suspect you've already got the basic idea, and can read the reference docs if you need the details, hopefully…)

Comment: It certainly makes more sense than it did. Will have to keep trying thins out. Thanks!

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: If you practice mapping between complex comprehensions and the equivalent loop code (referring to the reference docs and/or trial-and-erroring if you get lost), after a few times back and forth, it should suddenly click in your head, and from them on, multi-clause comprehensions are obvious (except the ones that get too long to parse in your head… but the same is true with English, and just as in English you shouldn't write statements that are too long to parse in your head, like this one for example).

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data=[{'a':54,'b':1},{'a':25,'b':0},{'a':53,'b':1},{'a':532,'b':2},{'a':132,'b':0}]

output = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    output[d['b']].append(d['a'])

output = sorted((k, v) for k, v in output.items())

print output
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[(0, [25, 132]), (1, [54, 53]), (2, [532])]
```

Comment: This is way better than what I had.

Comment: This is pretty slick as well!

Comment: This gives you a (default)dict rather than a list, which of course means it's not in sorted order… but you can always sort the dict's values, using the corresponding keys as the sort key, in one more line.

Comment: @abarnert: Didn't see the sorted requirement - now it gets sorted too.

Answer (score 1):

A posible (and compact) solution is:

```
output= { ok: [ ie['a'] for ie in list if ie['b'] == ok ] for ok in { e['b'] for e in list } }
```

Note that `{ e['b'] for e in list }` is a set comprehension (relatively new feature of the language).  Roughly equivalent to `set([ e['b'] for e in list ])`

I tested it on CPython 3.3.2, and it produces exaclty the expected result, except that in a dictionary.  IMHO, the lists are more useful in a dictionary than somewhere else, but to comply with the question:

```
list_0= output[0]
list_1= output[1]
list_2= output[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist=[{'a':54,'b':1},{'a':25,'b':0},{'a':53,'b':1},{'a':532,'b':2},{'a':132,'b':0}]

>>> zerolist, onelist, twolist = [], [], []
>>> for x in mylist:

        if 0 in x.values():
            zerolist.append(x['a'])
        elif 1 in x.values():
                onelist.append(x['a'])
        elif 2 in x.values():
                onelist.append(x['a'])
>>> >>> zerolist
[25, 132]
```